# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at all points except $0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, analysis, derivatives

My problem is as follows:

Let $a, b$ be positive numbers and define the function $f$ by the formula

$$f(x) =\begin{cases} \begin{array}{ll}
  |x|^a \sin\left(\dfrac{1}{|x|^b}\right)  & \mbox{if } x \ne 0, \\
  0 & \mbox{if } x = 0
 \end{array}\end{cases}$$

**Prove that $f$ is differentiable at all points except $0$ and compute its derivative.**

So I know how to find if $f$ is differentiable at some point using:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

But how would I solve it for the highlighted question above?

Comment: which one and why not? Did I make a typo?

Comment: The definition of $f$ *makes sense*. To calculate the derivative at $x>0$ you use the product and the chain rule. Same for $x<0\,.$

Comment: I rechecked for any typos but there aren't any, that is exacly how it was written for me.

Comment: Yes Yes my bad it didn't save my edit, fixed it now. Thank you!

Comment: Back to work. Can you use the hint in my first comment?

Comment: Not quite I think, well I know those terms, and that we'll need to apply them but still don't get the rest.

Comment: Which rest? It could help a great deal if you edited your question to write down what you know so far. MSE requires own efforts from OPs.

Comment: So my guess was to prove this we'll need to show that lim as h approaches 0- is not equal to lim as h approaches 0+, which would show that f is not differentiable at 0, right?

Comment: Hint on that: The right derivative of $f$ at zero is (if it exists - but it won't):
$$
\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{h^a\sin\big(\frac{1}{h^b}\big)}{h}
$$
Use L'Hospital and the derivative of $f(h)$ for $h>0$ from the first part of the question.

Comment: Alright, That's the part I got wrong. Can you explain shortly how you got the derivative of f?

Comment: I realize now that for $a>1$ that limit exists. So the question is a bit incomplete: the function is not differentiable at $0$ when $a\in [0,1]$. Regarding how I got the derivative of $f$. I did not get it. I gave you a hint in my first comment so that you can get it.

Comment: Alright so what do you mean with incomplete?

Comment: Read my comment word for word.

Comment: Yes well like I said everything should be complete, because that's exactly what problem I got on my exercice sheet.

Comment: Can you kindly accept Lorenzo Pompili's answer? If not why not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the fact that the above function is differentiable at $x=0$ if $a>1$, so either the problem wants to ask something impossible, or there is a typo.
Assume $a\leq 1$ then. To show that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, one simply needs to show that the limit you wrote above does not exist, that is, either one of the two limits from the left and from the right does not exist, or they both exist and are different.
The above limit, for $a=0$, reads
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)/x, $$
since $f(0)=0$. Now a small trick: $f$ is an even function, that is, $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$. So, the function $g(x):=f(x)/x$ is odd ($g(x)=-g(-x)$ for all $x$), so the above limit, if it exists, it must be zero (in fact, the limit as $x\to0^+$ is the opposite of the limit as $x\to0^-$ whenever one of the two limits exists; you can think of this from a graphical point of view, or you can prove it rigorously substituting $g(x)$ with $-g(-x)$ in the limit). Thus, to show that the limit does not exist, i.e., to show that $f$ is not differentiable in $x=0$, we simply need to show that the limit from the right is not zero.

So, now the math. We want to show that
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)/x $$
is not zero (or does not exist). Let’s rewrite a little bit better using the definition of $f$ and using the fact that $x$ is positive:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{a-1}\sin(x^{-b}). $$
How do we show that the above limit does not exist? Well… by hand. Consider the sequence $$ x_k=((2k+1/2)\pi)^{-1/b}. $$ Note that $x_k\to 0^+$ as $k\to \infty$. Then, substituting, $f(x_k)=(x_k)^{a-1}$, since $\sin((2k+1/2)\pi)=1$ for integer $k$. Since $a\leq 1$, the sequence $f(x_k)$ does not go to zero (more precisely, it converges to $1$ if $a=1$ and it diverges to $+\infty$ if $a<1$). So, the above limit cannot be zero.

Comment: +1 but replace $(2k+1)\pi$ by $(2k+1/2)\pi$ ;-)